# Use a Matlab project in Java

Tags: java, matlab, jar, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Is there any way of using a Matlab project in a java project? I researched and there is a tool named **Matlab builder JA** which converts a Matlab project into a jar. I sent them a request for the product and they never replied. Are there any other way of using the Matlab project in the java project or is there a way of getting a free trail of Matlab builder JA as soon as possible? The Matlab project is an image processing project and I just need to run the project and to get the output.

Comment: Maybe this can be help you https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/

Comment: The most fundamental information would be if you have a working copy of Matlab or not.

Comment: Angelo Immediata: Does it work properly? Have you tried it? 
bdecaf: Yes my copy of Matlab is working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a free trial of MATLAB Builder JA, just go to the [product page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/javabuilder/), and click the link on the right that says "Product Trial". You should be able to immediately download a short-term (about 15 days) trial without needing any involvement from a human at MathWorks.

However, if you call sales on the phone, I'm sure they can arrange for a trial pretty quickly as well.

Bear in mind, though, that the .jar files output by trial copies of MATLAB Builder JA **expire** at the same time as the end of the trial period (the same is true of the components produced by MATLAB Compiler, and the other Builder products).

Comment: Sam Roberts: It has been 5 days now and they still didn't reply. Anyways, your answer was so helpful because even if I got it, I would have been in trouble because I didn't know that the .jar file will also be expired in 15 days. Thank you! :)